# How to Dynamically add/remove directive AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the Angular Ellipsis directive (here: https://github.com/dibari/angular-ellipsis) to put some ellipsis on text that overflows. Here is the code that does this for the text contained in the scope variable 'fullText'.

```
<div data-ng-bind="fullText" data-ellipsis></div>
```

I'd like also, to have the ability to show the full text, un-ellipsised (if that is a word...) when I click on a button, say. This directive doesn't give me a easy way to do that, as far as I can tell.

What is the best AngularJS way to do this? I am pretty new to AngularJS and haven't yet written any directives yet - is there a non directive way to do this elegantly?

Comment: You can use removeAttr  to remove the attribute.removeAttr is a jquery function but angular wraps jquery lite with itself, so you can safely use it
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` or `ng-show`/`ng-hide` :

```
<div data-ng-bind="fullText" data-ellipsis ng-if="condition"></div>
<div data-ng-bind="fullText" ng-if="!condition"></div>
<button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button>

// In controller :
$scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.condition = !$scope.condition;
}
```

But the best way is to have the directive handle it directly.

Comment: Hi Magus - that makes sense - it is what I thought I could do.. but this creates two div's in memory for each place you want to do it, correct? Which is a fairly big overhead? Would using a directive be much more efficient?

Comment: With a directive you'll have only one div so yes it is better.

Comment: You can write your own custom directive that wraps your `div` and attaches or detaches the `data-ellipsis` directive based on the inputs you provide to the directive.Though it is possible, but I would suggest using ng-if is a simpler approach as creating a custom directive would require you to `$compile` the html string which would itself add to time complexity.